# Triggering a keyup event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, events, plugins

So I'm building a "Find an Installer Near You" feature that allows a user to fill out an input field with their zip code on Page1. Then when they click search it redirects them to Page2, Find an Installer Page, and fills out a search box with the zip code. I have gotten everything working with the zip code fill out and transferring the data to the new page via url, but I can't manage to get a .keyup event to succesfully trigger once the zip code is set as the value in the search box. The keyup will cause the results to refresh and make the user happy to see their results.

Here's the code I have thus far, any help/recommendations will be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**: For reference I'm using the Wordpress Google Maps Pro plugin developed by Flippercode.

```js
// Grab the value when the user clicks the search button,
// and encode it in the url.
$(function () {
    $("#zip-search").bind("click", function () {
        var url = "../find-an-installer?zipField=" + encodeURIComponent($("#zip-field").val());
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});

// Decode the url and grab the value.
var queryString = new Array();
$(function () {
    if (queryString.length == 0) {
        if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
            var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                queryString[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }
    // Make sure the value is present, and set variables.
    if (queryString["zipField"] != null) {
        var data = "";
        data += queryString["zipField"];
        var userZip = data;

    }

    // Place the value in the search box
    $(function fillValue() {
        $(".wpgmp_search_input").val(userZip);
        console.log("Fill value ran succesfully");
    });

    // Need to figure out how to trigger a keyup once the value is filled,
    // so the search function fires and updates the results.


});
```

Comment: just call `$("#zip-search").click();` after you set the value in your `textbox`

Answer (score 1):

And literally as I posted my question I finally figured it out. Although this may not be the most semantic, so I'm definitely open to improving this solution.

```js
// Grab the value when the user clicks the search button,
// and encode it in the url.
$(function () {
    $("#zip-search").bind("click", function () {
        var url = "../find-an-installer?zipField=" + encodeURIComponent($("#zip-field").val());
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});

// Decode the url and grab the value.
var queryString = new Array();
$(function () {
    if (queryString.length == 0) {
        if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
            var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                queryString[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }
    // Make sure the value is present, and set variables.
    if (queryString["zipField"] != null) {
        var data = "";
        data += queryString["zipField"];
        var userZip = data;

    }

    // Place the value in the search box
    $(function fillValue() {
        $(".wpgmp_search_input").val(userZip);
        console.log("Fill value ran succesfully");
        // Added this line to fire the keyup
        $('.wpgmp_search_input').keyup();
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see the `keyUp` event in your code? what exactly is your `keyUp` event going to do?

Comment: I added it in the last line of the fillValue function –

$('.wpgmp_search_input').keyup();

So what it's doing in my case is causing a list of results to refresh based on the new search_input value. This was the easiest way I could find to do it externally without modifying to core plugin files.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Grab the value when the user clicks the search button,
// and encode it in the url.
$(function () {
    $("#zip-search").bind("click", function () {
        var url = "../find-an-installer?zipField=" + encodeURIComponent($("#zip-field").val());
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});

// Decode the url and grab the value.
var queryString = new Array();
$(function () {
    if (queryString.length == 0) {
        if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
            var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                queryString[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    // Make sure the value is present, and set variables.
    if (queryString["zipField"] != null) {
        var data = "";
        data += queryString["zipField"];
        var userZip = data;

    }

    // Place the value in the search box
    $(function fillValue() {
        //if a regular event
        $(".wpgmp_search_input").val(userZip).keyup();
        //if a custom function you've bind
        $(".wpgmp_search_input").val(userZip).trigger("myCustomEvent:keyup");
        console.log("Fill value ran succesfully");
    });
});
```